How does Solidity call functions defined in interfaces without explicit logic?
How does this solidity function return the value 4 when I didn't define any logic in AggregatorV3interface?
 function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
        return AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306).version();
    }

I'm trying to use Aggregator function of chainlink contract but confused bit how it's working.

Interfaces define the function signatures (name, input types, and return types) that other contracts must implement. They are used to ensure that a contract adheres to a specific set of rules or interactions. Think of an interface as a job description that must be followed but without the details of how the job is done. Think about a delivery driver. Its job description that must be followed:

Get Package: Pick up the package.

Drive to Location: Drive the vehicle to the delivery location.

Deliver Package: Hand over the package.


The company doesn’t care how each driver accomplishes these tasks, as long as they do it. Some drivers may use a car, while others may use a bike or a scooter.
The address (0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306) is the location of the contract deployed on the blockchain. Each smart contract on Ethereum has a unique address where it lives, similar to how a website has a unique URL.
While the interface itself doesn't provide the function implementations, it tells you what functions you can call on that contract and what types of arguments or return values those functions expect. The interface is like a contract’s "USER MANUAL".
